# Adding export to PNG functionality to OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, html2canvas

I've combined html2canvas with OpenLayers ver 6.1.1 to provide, what I hope is, a better example of exporting to PNG.

I tried to incorporate the example shown on the OpenLayers site in my application, but it didn't work on all browsers (esp. Safari).

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/html2canvas.min.js'></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/FileSaver.js/1.3.3/FileSaver.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=fetch,requestAnimationFrame,Element.prototype.classList,URL,Promise"></script>
```

Using these javascript libraries and the current version of OpenLayers (6.1.1), I've added a button displayed on my map which has the following function:

```js
var button_p = document.createElement('button');
button_p.innerHTML = 'PNG';
button_p.title = 'Export map as png.';

var pngfunction = function() {
  map.once('rendercomplete', function(event) {
    html2canvas(document.getElementById('map')).then(function(canvas) {
      var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
      var now = new Date();
      var monthy = now.getMonth() + 1; // remember months are stored in array numbered 0-11
      ctx.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
      ctx.font = "12px Arial";
      ctx.fillText(monthy + "-" + now.getDate() + "-" + now.getFullYear() + " " + now.getHours() + ":" + (now.getMinutes() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getMinutes() + ":" + (now.getSeconds() < 10 ? '0' : '') + now.getSeconds(), 10, 20);

      if (navigator.msSaveBlob) {
    navigator.msSaveBlob(canvas.msToBlob(), 'map.png');
      } else {
    canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
      saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
        });
      }
    });
  });
  map.renderSync();
};
button_p.addEventListener('click', pngfunction, false);
```

Since this button is part of the 'ol-control' class and I don't want those controls to be part of the resulting PNG, I round up these items and apply the following code which removes these controls from the PNG:

```js
var removals = document.getElementsByClassName('ol-control');
for(var i=0; i < removals.length; i++) { removals[i].setAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore','true'); }
```

But, since I want to see the north arrow, I remove this attribute I just added to that control using the following:

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('ol-rotate')[0].removeAttribute('data-html2canvas-ignore');
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Thanks for sharing your approach. For the benefit of everybody (and to follow this site standards), you can write a question about your goal  and provide your code as an answer.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [ol-et Print control](https://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/canvas/map.control.print.html) to get an image of an ol map.

Answer (score 0):

I use this to export an ol-map to png:

```js
map.once('rendercomplete', function() {
    var target = map.getViewport();
    // options for html2canvas to filter out all the 'ol-control' elements
    var configOptions = {
        ignoreElements: function(target) {
            return (target.className.indexOf('ol-control') !== -1); },
        logging: false
    };
    html2canvas(target, configOptions)
        .then(function(canvas) {
            canvas.toBlob(function(blob) {
            saveAs(blob, 'map.png');
            });
    });
});
```